# Insert Data mysql using Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am want insert data to MySQL Database using Ajax and PHP
My Ajax Code

```
 $(function(){
        $('#submit').click(function(){
        var Name = $('#InputName').val();
        var Email = $('#InputEmail').val();
        var Phone = $('#InputPhone').val();
        var Username = $('#InputUser').val();
        var Status = $('#selectStatus').val();



        //Ajax for add Dealer
        $.ajax({
            url     : "../page/addnewDealer.php",
            type    : "POST",
            async   : false,
            data    :{
                Submit:'adduser',
                Name : Name,
                Email:Email,
                Phone:Phone,
                UserName:Username,
                Status:Status

            },
            success :function(result){
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
    });
```

and PHP code is

```
 if(isset($_POST['Submit'])=='adduser')
    {
        $pass= get_rand_id();
        $time= get_currunt_Time();
        $insertData = "INSERT INTO tbl_dealer (dlrUsrnme,dlrPaswrd,isactive,contName,contPhone,contEmaill,lastUpdtTime,creationTime) VALUES('$_POST[Username]','$pass','$_POST[Status]','$_POST[Name]','$_POST[Phone]','$_POST[Email]','$time','$time')";

        $result = mysql_query($insertData);
    }
```

It is a registration page when i am add a user using this program . program replies success massage but in database  nothing happen

Comment: You're wide open to SQL injection...

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$insertData = "INSERT INTO tbl_dealer (dlrUsrnme,dlrPaswrd,isactive,contName,contPhone,contEmaill,lastUpdtTime,creationTime) VALUES('$_POST[Username]','$pass','$_POST[Status]','$_POST[Name]','$_POST[Phone]','$_POST[Email]','$time','$time')";
```

to

```
$insertData = "INSERT INTO tbl_dealer (dlrUsrnme,dlrPaswrd,isactive,contName,contPhone,contEmaill,lastUpdtTime,creationTime) VALUES('".$_POST[Username]."','".$pass."','".$_POST[Status]."','".$_POST[Name]."','".$_POST[Phone]."','".$_POST[Email]."','".$time."','".$time."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add braces { } around your $_POST variables in the query.  Also, check your spelling of your field names - is "contEmaill" correct?  (Two 'l's).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take post data to a variable and append it to the sql query.